# bootstrap - disable input hover color

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3.

I have a simpel text-input

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control pn-input" data-provide="typeahead" id="searchfield">
        <span class="input-group-addon pn-span">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

When i hover the input the border-color changes to blue, i've been searching the css for hours and i can't find where this color is defined.

Comment: Have a look at `.form-control:focus { ... }` ;-)

Comment: create a link to your page. I will say you the solution

Comment: What about when i click it? should be something like .form-control:active? cant find it tho

Comment: `:focus` is the pseudo selector for when you click on it, ie it gains focus. That's were you'll find the CSS for the blue colour. `Line 1708` in the `non-minified` version of the latest `bootstrap.css` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

working fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/9H4Ea/3/ with bootstrap input focused without boxshadow and bordercolor set to gray.

```
.form-control:focus {border-color:rgba(100,100,100,1)!important;
-webkit-box-shadow: none!important;
    -moz-box-shadow: none!important;
    box-shadow: none!important;
}
```

**important**
if you override bordercolor property in this way

```
border-color:#fff;
```

it doesn't work because remains the *opacity* of bootstrap that is 0.8 (assigned with *rgba*)